# 301redirect issue in Gatsby.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, http-status-code-301, gatsby-plugin

I'm using gatsby.js with hundreds of blogs but I migrated the website with some reason.
So original blogs's urls were like `localhost:8000/blog/3-Best-Football-Shoe` and those are well organized with SEO. But the new developed gatsby has `localhost:8000/3-Best-Football-Shoe`. So I need to make the 301 redirect in gatsby website. The website is hosting on AWS. Hope someone help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use (if not you probably should) Application Load Balancer, you could use Listener rule 301 redirect.